# ExecutorCompletionService running with only one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

While using executor service,iam getting only only single thread(For ex:" pool-8-thread-32") in the thread pool and its not calling the submitted task and it is returning as null.

And next run it running with the next sequence number thread (For ex:" pool-8-thread-33") and same issue.Actually the ExecutorService is initiated with 16 threads at the start.

Where iam doing wrong in the below code:

2023-03-01 12:18:32,976 INFO  (zara.matcher.MatcherHelper) [     pool-8-thread-32] r[,] doc::317428390

2023-03-01 12:18:32,976 INFO  (zara.matcher.MatcherHelper) [     pool-8-thread-32] r[,] adding futurejava.util.concurrent.FutureTask@119e3ac8

2023-03-01 12:18:32,976 INFO  (zara.matcher.MatcherHelper) [     pool-8-thread-32] r[,] doc::317450517

2023-03-01 12:18:32,976 INFO  (zara.matcher.MatcherHelper) [     pool-8-thread-32] r[,] adding futurejava.util.concurrent.FutureTask@73503a9b

2023-03-01 12:18:32,976 INFO  (zara.matcher.MatcherHelper) [     pool-8-thread-32] r[,] doc::225967259

public static final int THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

```
 public ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Math.max(this.cpu, THREADS));


public int parallelMatch(SolrDocumentList docList, List<PoraResult> matchedParties, MatchArgs args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    CompletionService<MatchCallerResult> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(this.executor);
    List<Future<MatchCallerResult>> allFutures = new LinkedList<>();
    int order = 0;
    for (SolrDocument doc : docList) {
      Future<MatchCallerResult> future = service.submit(new MatchCaller(order, doc, args));
      order++;
      logger.info("adding future"+future);
      allFutures.add(future);
    } 
    int len = allFutures.size();
    int finished = 0;
    MatchCallerResult[] allResults = new MatchCallerResult[len];
    while (finished < len) {
      Future<MatchCallerResult> future = null;
      try {
        future = service.poll(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (future == null) {
          finished++;
          break;
        } 
        MatchCallerResult mr = future.get();
        allResults[mr.order] = mr;
      } catch (Exception e) {
      } finally {
        finished++;
      } 
    } 
        
    public static class MatchCaller implements Callable<MatchCallerResult> {
   
    public MatcherHelper.MatchCallerResult call() throws Exception {
      
      MatcherHelper.MatchCallerResult mcr = new MatcherHelper.MatchCallerResult();
      return mcr;
    }
  }`enter code here`
```